# Save Data in Array, NOT TEMPORALLY

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, push

I use the following code to add entrys to a knowledgebase, this should be for me and my colleagues, but my Problem is that the entrys are only avaible in the actually session, when I has add them, but when I reload the site, they are lost, can you help me?

My code:

js:

```
var knowledgebase = angular.module('knowledgebase', []);
///////// --- Start of Data Simulation --- //////////
knowledgebase.controller('kbControl', function ($scope, $sce, $http) {
  $scope.tutorials = [
    {
      'topic': 'Oracle Metalink Porsche',
      'body': '<a href="https://support.oracle.com/CSP/ui/flash.html">https://support.oracle.com/CSP/ui/flash.html</a',
      'tags': 'Oracle,Metalink,Porsche,Login,Zugangsdaten',
      'value': '0',
      'negative': '0'
    },
    {
      'topic': 'Oracle Metalink',
      'body': '<a href="https://support.oracle.com/CSP/ui/flash.html">https://support.oracle.com/CSP/ui/flash.html</a>',
      'tags': '',
      'value': '0',
      'negative': '0'
    },
    {
      'topic': 'Oracle Metalink MLP',
      'body': '<a href="https://support.oracle.com/CSP/ui/flash.html">https://support.oracle.com/CSP/ui/flash.html</a>',
      'tags': '',
      'value': '0',
      'negative': '0'
    },
  ];
  $scope.predicate = 'topic';
  $scope.trust = function (html_code) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
  }
  $scope.quicklinks = [...];

  $scope.experts = [...];

  ///////// --- End of Data Simulation --- //////////
  ///////// --- Start of Lync Integration --- //////////  
  $scope.getID = function (username) {
    return username.replace('@', '_').replace('.', '_').replace('.', '_');
  };


  $scope.showLyncPresencePopup = function (event, userName) {...
  };

  $scope.getStatus = function (userName) {...
  };

  $scope.hideShowExperts = false;

  $scope.expertSort = function (expert) {...
  }

  var tutorial;
  tutorial = {
    'customer': '',
    'technology': '',
    'topic': '',
    'description': ''

  }
  $scope.submit = function (tutorial) {
    $scope.tutorials.push({
      'customer': $scope.tutorial.customer,
      'technology': $scope.tutorial.technology,
      'topic': $scope.tutorial.topic,
      'body': $scope.tutorial.description


    })
  };

});


///////// --- End of Lync Integration --- //////////

///////// --- Data Templates --- //////////
/*
  tutorials: {'topic':'','body':'','tags':'','customers':'','technology':''},
  quicklinks: {'name':'','address':''},
  experts: {'name':'','email':'','customers':'','technologies':''},
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="knowledgebase">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>DB Knowledgebase</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="kbController.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lyncInterconnect.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="kbControl">
        <div class="header maxwid h80 margbot10">
            <div id="logo" class="left marg5"></div>
            <h1 class="titlehead nomargtop">DB-Team Knowledgebase</h1>
            <div id="mobMenu"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu mobHidden left wid20">
            <ul class="nostyle nomarg nopad">
                <li>
                    <label>Customer:</label>
                    <select ng-model="selection">
                        <option value="">All</option>
                        <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
                        <option value="porsche">Porsche</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Technology:</label>
                    <select ng-model="technology">
                        <option value="">All</option>
                        <option value="oracle">Oracle</option>
                        <option value="mssql">MSSQL</option>
                        <option value="db2">DB2</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Filter:</label>
                    <input ng-model="query" class="maxwid">
                </li>
                <li class="miniinfo">Our knowledgebase consists of {{tutorials.length}} topics</li>
                <li class="miniinfo">Currently showing {{filtered.length}} topics</li>
                <li>
                    
                    <ul class="nostyle marg10 pad15 quicklinks">
                        <li><h4 class="nomarg">Quicklinks:</h4></li>
                        <li ng-repeat="link in quicklinks"><a class="blacktxt quicklink" href="{{link.address}}" target="_blank">{{link.name}}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="users" ng-hide="(experts | filter:selection | filter:technology).length == experts.length" ng-show="(experts | filter:selection | filter:technology).length < experts.length">
                <div>
                    <label>Available Colleagues</label>
                    <ul class="nostyle marg10 pad15">
                        <li ng-repeat="expert in experts | filter:selection | filter:technology | orderBy: expert.name">
                            <div id="{{getID(expert.email)}}" class="{{getStatus(expert.email)}}" ng-mouseover="showLyncPresencePopup($event, expert.email)" ng-mouseout="hideLyncPresencePopup()"><span class="user">{{expert.name}}</span></div>
                        </li>
                        <li ng-show="(experts | filter:selection | filter:technology).length == 0">No colleagues found that match your current filter criteria</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right wid80 lightgraybg topics">
            <div class="card margbot10 pad15" ng-repeat="tutorial in filtered = (tutorials | filter:query | filter:selection | filter:technology | orderBy:predicate)">
            <h3>{{tutorial.topic}}</h3>
            <hr noshade class="cardhr"/>
            <p ng-bind-html="trust(tutorial.body)" class="normarg nopad"></p>
            <p><span class="votetext green">This was helpful!</span><span class="votetext"> / </span><span class="votetext red">This did not help me</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="card margbot10 pad15" ng-show="(tutorials | filter:query | filter:selection | filter:technology | orderBy:predicate) == 0">
                <h4>No entry found that match your filter criteria.</h4>

            <form>
                <label>Customer:</label></br>
                <select ng-model="tutorial.customer">
                    <option value="">All</option>
                    <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
                    <option value="porsche">Porsche</option>
                    
                </select></br>
                <label>Technology:</label></br>
                <select ng-model="tutorial.technology">
                    <option value="">All</option>
                    <option value="oracle">Oracle</option>
                    <option value="mssql">MSSQL</option>
                    <option value="db2">DB2</option>
                </select></br>
                <label>Topic:</label></br>
                <input type="text" maxlength="100" size="49" ng-model="tutorial.topic"/></br>
                <label>Description:</label></br>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" ng-model="tutorial.description">

                </textarea></br>
                <button type="submit" ng-click="submit()">Add entry</button>
                <button type="reset">Reset</button>

            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            
            jQuery('#mobMenu').bind('click',function(){
                
                $(this).toggleClass('rotation');
                $('.menu').toggleClass('mobHidden');
                
            })
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: You should probably have a look at localstorage and sessionstrorage - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store and share data between browsers you will need a website to store your data. You can save and load data with with angulars [AJAX API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

There are many ways to store data on a webserver. But you will need server side code to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use HTML5?

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

```
var foo = localStorage.getItem("bar");
// ...
localStorage.setItem("bar", foo);
```

If you want to save arrays, use the JSON.parse and JSON.stringify functions, as the local storage only accepts strings